# WEBRTC AUDIO does not function on ios 16 but functions on android perfectly

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, webrtc, sip

after trying and failing to spot the difference here during troubleshooting, i have noticed a fundamental bug on iOS 16 mainly safari, which is when using SIP.js i am unable to make a call nor send or receive any audio via WEBRTC

there are no errors in the console or logs on the browser/ side, but strangely enough this works on android.

is there something defunct in ios 16 for WEBRTC comms, that i am missing?

Thanks

browser console logs on android and ios
expected ios to function like the android version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: its the same code used here https://github.com/onsip/SIP.js